# Error when dropdownlist.databind() if I change from FormView.EditMode to FormView.InsertMode

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, drop-down-menu, formview

I have a FormView like:

```
<EditItemTemplate>
    <th>Test Name</td>
    <td><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblSuite" Text='<%# Eval("Suite") %>'></asp:Label></td>
</EditItemTemplate>
<InsertItemTemplate>
    <th>Test Name</td>
    <td><asp:DropDownList ID="insertSuite" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList></td>
</InsertItemTemplate>
```

Which means in InsertMode, the user can change `Suite` using a dropdownlist while in EditMode, the user can only see `Suite` but cannot do modification.
If the user click one of the record, FormView was changed into EditMode with the code:

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //getDatasource
    FormView1.DataSource = objList;
    FormView1.ChangeMode(FormViewMode.Edit);
    FormView1.DataBind();
}
```

If the user click the `Add New` button, FormView was changed into InsertMode with the code:
FormView1.ChangeMode(FormViewMode.Insert);

```
protected void btnAddSingle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FormView1.ChangeMode(FormViewMode.Insert);

    DropDownList drp = (DropDownList)FormView1.FindControl("insertSuite");
    drp.DataSource = otherRepo.SuiteDropdownListDataSource(2);
    drp.DataTextField = "Name";
    drp.DataValueField = "Name";
    drp.DataBind();
}
```

My Problem is:
If I click the one of the record and get into EditMOde, Then click the `Add New` button, Then error occured.
the `(DropDownList)FormView1.FindControl("insertSuite")` is null.

I thought it was something about lifecycle but cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to `DataBind` the FormView after you've called `ChangeMode` and before `FormView1.FindControl`.

So this works:

```
FormView1.ChangeMode(FormViewMode.Insert);
FormView1.DataBind();
DropDownList drp = (DropDownList)FormView1.FindControl("insertSuite");
```

Comment: It seemed a little weired to me. If I don't have the dropdownlist I will have no existed data to `bind` because I use InsertMode to add new data. What am I binding to FormView?

Comment: @hbrlovehaku: actually the DropDownList does not exist before you change the FormViewMode **and** DataBind the FormView(to nothing in Insert-Mode). Unless it isn't rebound it uses the old datasource and hence the old controls(edit-mode). If you change the mode after first bidning you also discard current template with all bounded values and data binding has to be called again to fill in controls from template for new mode.